# Funny for loop behavior?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a tableview controller in which I would like to be able to select 2, and only 2 cells at a time. If you already have 2 cells checked and you tap another unchecked cell, the 1st cell will uncheck and the most recent 2 will now be checked. Here is what I am using unsuccessfully:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

         int count = 0;
    int i = 0;

    NSIndexPath *datPath = 0;
    for (UITableViewCell *cell in [self.tableView visibleCells]) {
        i++;
        datPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
        if([tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:datPath].accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark){
        count++;
        }
    }

    if(count == 0){
        firstChecked = indexPath;
        [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    }

    if(count == 1){
        secondChecked = indexPath;
        [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    }

    if(count == 2){
        [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:firstChecked].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        firstChecked = secondChecked;
        secondChecked = indexPath;
        [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    }

    NSLog(@"Count is equal to: %d",count);
```

for those wondering, I do have multiple selection allowed on my table view. What happens with the above code is the following. Count is off on value, so it allows me to check 3 times, then stops allowing me to check at all. Am I missing something? Thanks.

Comment: You're not unsetting the accessory type when you have two selected already; you're setting it again `[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:firstChecked].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You always check the same cell inside your for loop (**indexPath** is the cell you are currently selecting):
`if([tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark)`